# How can I fix "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous" Error?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have tried several things but did not succeed. The line of code causing the error is something like this:

```
def check(a,b):
        return a-b>1
df=df[(df['name']=='john') & (check(df['date'],df['salary'])==False))]
```

The error I'm getting is:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I suspect it's due to the second condition of the statement.. but I'm not sure how to fix that, i.e., how to pass the specific values of **date** and **salary** to the **check** function (instead of passing the whole column)?

Comment: First, you need to show us what `check1` is. Second, what is your error? Third, when you do `df['name'] == 'blah'` you need to put it in brackets (parens in AmE) if there are multiple conditions. (Or otherwise use `df['name'].eq('blah')`.)

Comment: to simplify.. check function takes in 2 integer values a and b as arguments and returns (a-b)>1

Comment: Put the code for `check` in the question.

Comment: Also put your error traceback in your question.

Comment: the posted code works fine on my end (except an extra parentheses). we need sample data/code that we can directly use to reproduce the issue

Comment: also is `date` really an int? why would you subtract `salary` from `date`?

Comment: Well the actual code is not simply subtracting.. it's very long and complicated, so I oversimplified it in my post.

I was able to fix the issue by adding a column df.loc[i,'check']=check(df.loc[i,'date'],df.loc[i,'salary'])
so the filtering became:
df=df[(df['name']=='john') & (df['check']==False))]